# Calendar Management in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, calendar

I am given a task to Make an Appointment Management system for Patient Appointment.

Things i have to do are:
On calender link there should open a calender, there will b a link by clicking which user will have a form to get appointment. On admin side, admin can approve appointments and those will be displayed on calender on front end .
As i am new to symfony. i don't even know how to take a start for a calender.
can anyone please guide me what to follow and which one is the best for front and back end calender management, to synchronize with my application.

plus necessary steps to get me desired result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[adsigns/calendar-bundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle) is an easy way to get started.  This uses [jQuery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for the frontend and some simple Symfony listeners to generate events for ajaxy callbacks from FullCalendar via [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).  (The FOSJsRoutingBundle is a very nice bundle that makes it possible to generate URLs from Symfony routes in JavaScript.)

Since you will be dealing with time, which is always troublesome, you will probably want to familiarize yourself with [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) (recently integrated into FullCalendar v2) as well as [Moment.php](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php), a PHP port of MomentJS for the backend.  I've also heard good things about the PHP [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) library, though have not used it myself.

For even more sophisticated frontends, take a look at KendoUI's [Scheduler](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler) as well as the Sencha [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) Calendar.

Comment: Thanks A lot :) 
Just one more thing , i just heard that this adsigns/calendar-bundle  bundle just deal with event management, i-e admin can publish event etc. 
I started with this and left it without completing. Because my task is not event management its Appointment management , patient can register and admin can confirm and see calaneder , as i mentioned in Question, so not sure if its gonna help me in that :)

Comment: I think calendar-bundle will work for you; it just depends on how you implement on the backend.  For example, with calendar-bundle it would be easy to give patients a registration form with preferred time and date and then render this appointment to admin-facing and patient-facing calendars. BTW, you will probably also want to send iCalendar requests to patients so they can add to a local calendar.  Take a look at the Sabre VObject library (https://github.com/fruux/sabre-vobject) which makes this a lot easier.